# Pairwise distance matrix containing strings

Tags: matlab, distance

I need to calculate the pairwise distance between two matrix elements in a way that distance is equal to the number of binary differences between features/dimensions.
I want to do this with MATLAB codes without using a loop.
For example:
Assume I want to calculate the distance between instances in `A` and `B`:

```
A = [ 1 2 3 ; 2 3 4]         % (two instances with three features)

B = [ 2 3 4 ; 2 5 6 ; 4 5 6] % (three instances with three features)
```

I need to calculate `C`, which would be a 2x3 matrix contain the distance of instances in `A` and `B` in a way that the distance between `[1 3 3]` and `[2 3 4]` would be 2: comparing the features, when a feature is equivalent, add 0 to distance and when they are dissimilar add 1 to distance.
So in this case,

```
C = [3 3 3; 0 2 3].
```

`A` and `B` may contain strings instead of numbers.

Comment: I don't understand your statement:  ".. the distance between [1 3 3 ] and [2 3 4] would be 2:comparing the features, when a feature is similar add 0 to distance and when they are dissimilar add 1 to distance."  Could you clarify? Where does [1 3 3] come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) with `@ne` (not equal), followed by a `sum` to count the number of dissimilar features for an instance:

```
A = [1 2 3; 2 3 4];
B = [2 3 4; 2 5 6; 4 5 6];
C = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@ne,A,permute(B,[3 2 1])),2))

C =

     3     3     3
     0     2     3
```

The above works by generating a logical array testing for equality of each feature for each instance pair via `bsxfun(@ne,...)`.  Then a `sum` is performed over dimension 2 to count the number of dissimilar features for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist2.html) with Hamming distance already does this for you:

```
pdist2(A,B,'hamming')
```

This gives the result as *percentage* of coordinates that differ. Since you want *number* instead of percentage, multiply by the number of columns:

```
pdist2(A,B,'hamming')*size(A,2)

ans =

     3     3     3
     0     2     3
```